# Is there MySQL example database like in Oracle?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, oracle

Sometime ago, when I installed Oracle on Ubuntu, there was a sample database. Database contained Employees, Departments, ...

Now I wonder is there something similar for MySQL?

Comment: Well I don't really know how it is called, but when I tried to load example database (employee data) from MySQL the "load_employees.dump" file crashes, since it is to large to handle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [any sample MySQL databases I can download?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609/any-sample-mysql-databases-i-can-download)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not installed automatically with MySQL, no.

See this link for samples you can download: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609/any-sample-mysql-databases-i-can-download

Answer (score 1):

You can download MySQL sample databases [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html).

Comment: As I mantioned earlier in my comment, there  is realy realy large file in employees database "load_employees.dump". About 16Mb.

Comment: @Eugene, you should use the employee.sql file.

Comment: After downloading the Employee database from https://launchpad.net/test-db/, follow the instructions from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employee.html.